# input annotations quality check for large scale image data

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, datasets

while dealing with image data at very large scale, there are different sources where data is coming from. Often, we do not have any control over quality of labels/ annotations. I already do use sampling quality checks method to manually check the quality of annotations but as the volume of data has increased,even sampling QC become an inefficient job. Are there other methods to automate / simplify this task for data at large scale?